# MySQL: Query This Week Data

Tags: mysql, select

currently I am working with MySQL and I want to do query to select data.

Suppose I have bellow table:

**Photo**

Id*

Photo_url

Photo_name

Date_upload

User_id

Then, I want to get the photo which uploaded within this week. I mean that: if today is Tuesday 21 October 2014, then the system will get photo, which uploaded from Monday 20 October 2014 until now.
Or if it Saturday 18 October 2014, then the system should return photo, which uploaded from Monday 13 October 2014.

Also how is the query if I want to get previous week data? I mean if today is Tuesday 21 October 2014, I want to get photo, which uploaded from Monday, 13 October 2014 until Sunday 19 October 2014?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your desired Monday is `$desiredDate`. To use it in MySQL, you'd need to format it properly:

```
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $desiredDate);
```

Then you just need to select the right data, something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT photo_url, photo_name
FROM photos
WHERE date_upload > DATE($mysqlDate)
  AND date_upload < DATE_ADD($mysqlDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
```

So, when parsed, it should look something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT photo_url, photo_name
FROM photos
WHERE date_upload > DATE('2014-10-13 00:00:00')
  AND date_upload < DATE_ADD('2014-10-13 00:00:00', INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
```

MySQL has plenty of good time functions, see the docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

If you keep upload dates as Unix timestamps, it's even simpler:

```
$query = "SELECT photo_url, photo_name
FROM photos
WHERE date_upload > $mysqlDate
  AND date_upload < $mysqlDate + 60*60*24*7"; /* 60*60*24*7 represents number of seconds in 7 days */
```